How to configure spring boot web service for message decryption?
I'm trying to get a spring boot webservice up and running that is able to decrypt a request using the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.
Without encryption the server works fine. But if I enable encryption the server says:
No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData]

I've setup a minimal demo project using spring boot 3.4.0 here: github project
Does anybody have an idea why this is not working as expected? And how to do it right?

At first glance remove @EnableWs, ditch the @Bean for the MessageDispatcherServlet. Let your WsSecurityConfig implement WsConfigurer and implement the addInterceptors method. Ditch the @Bean for the list of interceptors it adds nothing. You are trying to hard and working around the auto-configuration, infact you are disabling it.

I tried to follow your comments, but it was'nt successful: https://github.com/jpw-src/spring-boot-webservice-demo/tree/suggestion-m-deinum
Or did I miss something?

I think using encryption is only useable in combination with a soap action for the actual routing. The message is only decrypted after the endpoint has been selected and before calling the method. At least that is what it looks like when debugging. Looking at some samples with other technology they also appear to be using a soap action next to encryption.
